# Get running status of mongodb

Tags: shell-script, services, mongodb

Having a script where I start/stop various services depending on what I need. For example Apache, BIND, MySQL, PostFix, Memcached, Tomcat, ... and so on.

Depending on status options to script etc. various actions are taken.

For most this works fine: (example with Apache)

```
if service apache2 status >/dev/null; then
    # ... do some action
fi
```

For others one have to use other tricks like `mysqladmin ping`.

However I'm not able to find any good way to check status for `mongodb`.

```
service mongodb status
```

It has the same *"sickness"* as MySQL and yield `mongodb stop/waiting` and also evaluates to true, even if service is not up and running.

Have looked at `mongod`, `mongostat` etc. but not found any option for this.

One way could be to use `ps` or perhaps better `netstat` and combine either with `grep` or the like, but wondering if there is a better (more native/targeted) way to check status. Could also grep for `stop/waiting`, but not sure how reliable this is, and guess it could likely break in a future upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about just using `pgrep` to find the process, `mongod`.

```
$ pgrep mongod
```

Comment: Wondered if there was some more direct way like `mysqladmin ping`, but can't find any. I'll accept this as it is good as any I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried mongodb. But from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091624/is-mongodb-running), I see `ps` options as you had mentioned in your quesiton. Also, you had mentioned only `service mongodb status`. However, you can also try `/etc/init.d/mongod status`.

check with either:

```
   ps -edaf | grep mongo   # "ps" flags may differ on your OS
```

or

```
   /etc/init.d/mongod status
```

or

```
   service mongodb status
```

to see if mongod is running

check the log file `/var/log/mongo/mongo.log`  to see if there are any problems reported

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mongodb status` gives same exit as `service mongodb status`, as do `status mongodb`. No such file as `/etc/init.d/mongod`